# How to find an element on a page with WebDriver.io that doesn't have an identifier

Tags: typescript, webdriver-io, ui-testing

I want to find and run a test on this element:
[image]

It has a bunch of classes but those classes are used by other elements as well. How can I find this element on webdriver.io using Typescript?

Comment: Hey @oo92,
Did my answer help you? If so, please click "Mark Correct" on the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options to achieve that:

1. Find by partial text

   To find a anchor element whose visible text partially matches your search value, query it by using `*=` in front of the query string

   For instance:

   ```
   $('*=Total')
   ```
2. Find by certain text:

   The same technique can be applied to elements as well.

   For instance:

   ```
   $('span=Total: 137216');
   ```
3. Find by `xPath`

   To query elements via a specific `xPath`

   ```
   $('//body/div[1]/div[1]/main[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/span[1]')
   ```